# About models for parallel algorithms

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing

Is there a difference between an execution model and a computation model? Or the two terms refers to the same things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What are your thoughts?  What research have you done?  Where did you run across those terms?  How did they define them?  What's the context in which  you ran across those phrases?

Comment: Thanks for your answer D.W. In fact I know the PRAM and the BSP model, and I've heard from someone the term execution model. I would like to know if this person was refering to the computation model. I've looked at the Wiki page about execution model but that seems off-topic. I'm working on parallel algorithms and this person asked me to detail the execution model of a parallel algorithm.